# Fastlane Match does not recognise repository after changing URL

Tags: fastlane

After changing the match repository URL from

*ssh://git@192.0.1.34/Users/git/ios-provisioning-hq.git* to *ssh://git@172.16.0.34/Users/git/ios-provisioning-hq.git*

running the *match* command does not recognise that there is an match repository already setup and asks me to set an initial password:

`Enter the passphrase that should be used to encrypt/decrypt your certificates
This passphrase is specific per repository and will be stored in your local keychain
Make sure to remember the password, as you'll need it when you run match on a different machine (...)`

How can I fix this without setting up a new repository for match?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the keychain of the machine where you run fastlane and search for *match*
2. Delete the entry referring to your old URL named like *match_ssh://git@172.16.0.34/Users/git/ios-provisioning-hq.git* (Shouldn't make a difference but there is no reason to keep it)
3. Run *match change_password* from your project directory, enter your old password and a new one. You can use the same for old and new.

You should be able to provision again without *match nuke*